# Webmin - custom sql command with variables

Tags: mysql, webmin

I'm trying to add a custom command in webmin but I am getting the following error message:

```
execution error : called with 1 bind variables when 0 are needed
```

The variable name is startdate and so I have tried the following in my sql command:

```
BETWEEN '$startdate 00:00:00' AND '$enddate 23:59:59'
BETWEEN '? 00:00:00' AND  '? 23:59:59'
BETWEEN ':1 00:00:00' AND  ':2 23:59:59'
BETWEEN ? '00:00:00' AND ? '23:59:59'
BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

and with quotes round it but none replace with the desired variable.

Full command here

```
SELECT
  calldate,
  MAX(concurrent)+1 AS peakcount
FROM (
    SELECT
      DATE(a.calldate) as calldate,
      COUNT(b.uniqueid) AS concurrent
    FROM cdr AS a, cdr AS b
    WHERE  
      a.calldate BETWEEN '2013-11-08 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-13 23:59:59'
      AND (
        (a.calldate<=b.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate)+a.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate))
        OR (b.calldate<=a.calldate AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.calldate)+b.duration)>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.calldate))
      )
      AND a.uniqueid>b.uniqueid
    GROUP BY a.uniqueid
  ) AS baseview
GROUP BY calldate
```

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Your example attempts show only half of an expression, so it's hard to see exactly what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you want `BETWEEN ? AND` ?

Comment: I'm trying to put webmin varables where the date and time is BETWEEN '2013-11-08 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-13 23:59:59'

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in Webmin?

Comment: I'll ask again, have you tried `BETWEEN ? AND ?`

Comment: It doesn't work it just prints question marks and not the varable

Comment: It sounds like you're quoting the placeholders, rather than using the exact syntax I've now twice provided.

Comment: No I have tried BETWEEN '? 00:00:00'  BETWEEN ?' 00:00:00' and BETWEEN ? all return a question mark and not the vairable

Comment: Anyone have an idea why this doesn't work? A bug in webmin or my code?

Comment: So, I've suggested (three times) that you use `BETWEEN ? AND ?` and all you've done is reply that you've tried other things.  What more do you expect people to do?

Comment: It simply doesn't work. This is not the solution to this problem. Appreciate everyone who has taken a look thus far

Comment: Lets start off with some basics. Does it matter what the parameter names are in the webmin form? I currently have them set to 1 and 2

Comment: Perhaps there needs to be an alternate escape character set in some way

Comment: Does anyone actually know if this feature works or have an example of it working? Thanks